# Activator throws IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm developing a project in Play 2.4, and I run it using the activator UI.  I recently had to forcibly stop the app by pressing "Stop" on the UI, and I haven't been able to get it to work since.  Now, on ANY project I open using activator, it never even gets past building the project. It throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
Use 'last' for the full log.
```

First, I'm a noob to the UI (I'm used to Play 1.x), so I don't know what this refers to, or even where to enter such a command.  A more verbose error message would be very helpful

Second, why would activator suddenly have these issues?  I haven't changed any configuration files (or any files).  I had the same error a while back when it automatically updated from activator 1.3.2 to 1.3.4, but the error was gone once I restarted activator.

**Edit**

Though this is almost certainly related to the possible duplicate referenced, several things tell me the scenario is different. The file `.sbt/repositories` seems to work with only the two slashes, not the three mentioned in the referenced answer.  Also, changing the number of slashes in this file didn't solve anything when I encountered this problem.  The fact that this occurred in response to forced closure makes me suspect corruption of some config file somewhere, but this one didn't seem to be it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sbt 0.13.8 URI has an authority component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624099/sbt-0-13-8-uri-has-an-authority-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What caused this?  Still no clue.  But just deleting the `.sbt` folder in the root directory made sbt refresh everything from scratch.  All projects now work properly again.

Comment: Running into the exact same error and will try this today.

Comment: Confirmed resolved for me. On Windows the .sbt folder is under c:\users\{username}\.sbt

Comment: I tired deleting it. I installed it on 3 different machines. Still the same.
I am using activator 1.3.5.

Comment: I tried deleting both ~/.sbt and ~./activator on OS X 10.11 with activator 1.3.9, but still get the error.  Had to revert to activator 1.3.2 to make things work again.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exception when I was running a play app from the git bash shell.  Switching to the cygwin shell solved my problem--the `activator` shell script seems to handle cygwin but not the `mingw32` environment provided by git bash.

This is with version 1.3.6 of the activator jar.

Comment: git bash was my problem as well. Switched to Windows cmd shell and it works fine.